# AWS EKS Deployment working but cannot access from Internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have an EKS container and service that I can access from inside a cluster:

`exec -it pod/web-deployment-f66f86459-4xqtl -- /bin/sh`

When I `wget http://web` it works

However, I cannot figure out how to get from the Internet into the container.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: poc
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
#    - host: eks.com
     - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: web
                port:
                  number: 80
```

This creates an ingress controller and  `get ingress.networking.k8s.io/poc` gives me:

```
NAME   CLASS   HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
poc    alb     *                 80      100m
```

I'm missing something - how do I figure out which hostname to use and give this thing a public address?

This AWS stuff is *really* tricky. I have this working in Kubernetes on a cluster on a local server with just microk8s, and it's working inside my eks cluster.

What am I missing?